# AWS ELB not associating with EC2 everytime its switched on

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I’m having a personal website hosted at AWS EC2 with ELB. Today I have started my AWS EC2 instances (I had turned off due to non usage and Of course, I can save some cost) and tried to load my website via AWS Elastic loadbalancer public dns url but it was not coming up in my browser, instead of webpage I got a blank white page. So I checked my AWS EC2 instances and ELB services.

In the Elastic Load Balancer section, I can see that the status message is showing the registered AWS EC2 instances are “Out of Service”! I tried to change the health check parameter values, nothing happened! So I deregister the EC2 instances from the loadbalancer and register the same again. After few minutes the instances are coming up to “In Service”. It took sometime because the EC2 instances should register into the loadbalancer and health check. Finally I brought my website up.

**Solutions tried --**

If you have launched your instance in EC2-VPC, by default, the IP address associated with your instance does not change when you stop and then start the instance. However, when you stop and then start your EC2-VPC instance, your load balancer might take sometime to recognize that the stopped instance has started. During this time your load balancer is not connected to the restarted instance. I recommend that you reregister your restarted instance with the load balancer.

**My instance is in EC2-VPC and I tried the baove and when I re-register the instance falls back in the load balancer but otherwise I am just waiting to no avail. Any reason?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very common issue in for aws elb. What you can do is add following lines at 
end of your /etc/rc.local (assuming you are running linux box)

```
elb-deregister-instances-from-lb <load_balancer_name> --instances <instance-id>
elb-register-instances-with-lb <load_balancer_name> --instances <instance-id>
```

It first deregisters your instance from elb and then registers back the instance.

Regards

Rajarshi Haldar

Comment: Im running a windows box, where do i update for that ?

Comment: At first install ec2 command line tools. You will get detailed installation methods from the following url - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/set-up-ec2-cli-windows.html

Comment: then put the commands in a batch file and test it. When everything works fine install them as start up script. Follow the link below for windows startup script installations method - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770556.aspx